# CSS: Prevent pseduo-element from inheriting hover state

Tags: css

I have a button element that includes an arrow treatment in the design. I'm adding the arrow treatment using a pseudo-element. The button has an underline in the hover state, but I need the pseudo-element to not inherit that hover state. This is a problem I've solved before by using pointer-events:none, but it's not currently working. I'm stumped. Any input is appreciated.

```
<a class="button-big">Big Button</a>
```

Styles:

```
.button-big:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

   .button-big:after {
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     content: "\2192";
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 0.3rem;
     pointer-events: none;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
   }
```

Comment: Its output is correct as you are expecting. I can run it and see that arrow doesn't have any underline.

Comment: Interesting. Did you edit anything? If I isolate the code from the project to rule out any other conflicts, I'm still seeing the same issue. You can see it here: https://codepen.io/david-brown/pen/ZEKjgBN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow is part of `a` tag. So, the underline is showing according to the width of the anchor tag.

One solution is that you can move the arrow from calculating the width for anchor using `position: absolute`.

In this case your scss would be like

```
  .button {
  display: inline-flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: grey;
    line-height: 2;
    letter-spacing: -0.36px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
    justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
    //@include transition( all, 0.3s, ease-out );
  
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
  &.button-big {
    font-weight: bold;
    
    &:after {
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     content: "\2192";
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 0.3rem;
     vertical-align: middle;
     position: absolute;
     right: 60px;
    }
  }
}
```

Other solutions could be separate the element (text and arrow).

```
<a class="button button-big"><span>Big Button</span></a>
```

On hover, apply the underline to `span` element.

```
.button {
  display: inline-flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: grey;
    line-height: 2;
    letter-spacing: -0.36px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
    justify-content: center;
    //@include transition( all, 0.3s, ease-out );
  
  &:hover {
    span {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
  }
  
  &.button-big {
    font-weight: bold;
    
    &:after {
     font-family: FontAwesome;
     content: "\2192";
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 0.3rem;
     pointer-events: none;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
  }
}
```